# add javascript support to NetBeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans, ubuntu, ide, autocomplete

I'm developing project in ubuntu 11.04 and NetBeans 6.9.
In windows when I was working with NetBeans 7 ,it has got JavaScript complete ,but I can't find NetBean 7 in ubuntu and JavaScript plugin for NetBeans 6.9 to have auto complete.

now what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same. I originally download 6.9 but that wouldn't work.

Download version 7 and then install that. That version comes with JavaScript syntax highlighting.

Version 7: http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/7.0/final/

Answer (score 0):

You should find netbeans 7.0.1 for linux here: http://netbeans.org/downloads/ .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about auto-complete (because I can't stand auto-complete, it drives me crazy) but here's how you fix the syntax highlighting issue: [here it is.](http://ip-drankerne.dk/2011/02/netbeans-6-9-missing-javascript-highlight/)

The original poster might be asking how to fix it since Ruby on Rails is supposedly no longer supported after 6.9. (Personally, that's what I'm stuck with for this same reason.)